# Redireccionar una URL desde JavaScript a un controlador en MVC con Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo declarado lo siguiente en `angular.js`

```
.when('/plan', {
      templateUrl: 'Main/LinkTiless',
    controller: 'PlanCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'planEstudios'
```

No lo voy a mandar a una vista como se hace típicamente, `Content\Views\PlanEstudios` sino que lo deseo enviar a un controlador.

**Nota:** a manera de prueba en mi controlador trato de redireccionarlo a la página de google de la siguiente manera.

```
 public ActionResult LinkTiles()
 {            
      return Redirect("https://www.google.com");
 }
```

**Problema:** al dar clic en el ícono de Plan de estudios, no direcciona a ningún lugar, no ejecuta ninguna acción.

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De hecho, lo que se hace típicamente y el deber ser, es que la acción se envíe al `Controller`, y el `Controller` envía a un `View` un resultado. Me parece que la respuesta de @VEga solucionará tu problema

Comment: El problema es que no estoy trabajando con un localHost, estoy probando con la URL de google, para luego enviar la URL de un proyecto a otro servidor, entonces no se a que vista mandar el resultado.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que si vas a direccionar a otro server o a otro proyecto no requieres de una vista. En el link http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Fundamentals-of-an-MVC-Framework/81946 revisa el diagrama que viene y te podrás dar cuenta de cómo se genera el flujo de las peticiones utilizando MVC. Si quieres en algún momento direccionar a diferentes URLs inicialmente direccionando a un `Controller` lo puedes hacer con la instrucción `return Redirect("https://www.google.com");` justo como lo indica @VEga

Answer (score 3):

Parece ser que tienes algunos problemillas con los conceptos. No lo puedes enviar a una vista, debes enviar hacia una acción de un controlador.

Supongo que tienes un `Controller` llamado `Main` algo así:

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LinkTiles()
    {
         return Redirect("https://www.google.com");
    } 
}
```

De entrada tu código JavaScript manda llamar la accion equivocada pues tiene una "s" de más, en segunda revisa si puedes acceder directamente desde el navegador.

En caso que no quiera moverse desde Angular puedes hacer el `redirect` con

```
window.location = "@Url.Action("LinkTiles","Main")";
```

Comment: Hola, cuando cuando copié el código se me fue una "s" pero ese no es el problema, lo que me dices que, en caso de no querer moverse desde Angular.... gracias.

Comment: Ok para moverlo con window.location podria ser en un ng-click sobre los elementos, pero esto haria el refresh de toda la pagina, y con pierdes la interactividad que quieres tener con el route de Angular.
 seria buena idea si pasas el codigo que estas escribiendo, al parecer esta mal configurado, no se si tengas dos ng-app en el mismo html o si no estes descargando el angular-route.js

Comment: Tambien revisa tu consola (F12) a ver si aparece algun error